# Is it required to reset the shared_ptr object initialized in a function(local variable)? and global to the file?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Initialized global static shared_ptr object and passed to a function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<int> globalObj = std::make_shared<int>(5);

int testFunc(std::shared_ptr<int> obj1) {
    std::shared_ptr<int> localObj = obj1;
    std::cout<<"localObj.count:" << localObj.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "localObj:" << *localObj <<std::endl;
    localObj.reset();  -->** is it necessary to reset local count??**
    std::cout<<"localObj.count:" << localObj.use_count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"globalObj.count:" << globalObj.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"globalObj:" << *globalObj <<std::endl;
    
    testFunc(globalObj);
    
    std::cout<<"globalObj.count:" << globalObj.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"globalObj:" << *globalObj <<std::endl;
    
    globalObj.reset(); --> **is it necessary to reset global count??**
    std::cout<<"globalObj.count:" << globalObj.use_count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
globalObj.count:1
globalObj:5
localObj.count:3
localObj:5
localObj.count:3
globalObj.count:1
globalObj:5
globalObj.count:1
```

Does reset() affect the efficiency of the C++ program?

Comment: Why do you create `localObj` in the first place?

Comment: The count decreases when a `shared_ptr` is destroyed. You never need to think about managing it manually.

Comment: What is your design rationale for making 1) a global variable? 2) a shared_ptr. 
The reset is not necessary.  The only times I really need a shared_ptr is when there is shared ownership of threads with indeterminate lifetime (due to race conditions). 
In almost all other cases I can manage with life cycle by design (use shared_ptr too much and in big projects you almost always end up with an unwanted cyclic dependency).

Comment: @PepijnKramer: what is your approach to share components among your application (e.g. the model among plugins, or GUI)? I commonly use shared_ptr to share those big components (through revers dependency obviously). I mean, std::reference_wrapper is good, but is much less safe. On the other hand, std::unique_ptr cannot be copied/saved.

Comment: I give those components interfaces, I create instance in main (or very early in the lifecycle of my application) for small objects I can use the stack for big/polymorphic I use std::make_unique. For optional components I just inject non-owning raw pointer into the components that need the dependency, and for mandatory once a reference. In the end for most things there really should be only one owner.

Comment: @ Pepijn Kramer, If the raw pointer is injected, and the class object is initialized locally to another function (other than main), does it require cleaning the class members in the destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to reset, No.
The goal of the smart pointers: `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` is to make automatic the release of the memory, through RAII concept.

Releasing the smart pointer is, consequently, pointless in 99.9% of the cases.

Here is an example of your code with few clarifications:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class MyInt;
auto globalObj = std::make_shared<MyInt>(5);

class MyInt final
{
    int intVal;
public:
    MyInt()
    {
        std::cout << "Constucted!" << std::endl; 
    }
    
    MyInt(int nv ): intVal(nv)
    {
        std::cout << "Constucted!" << std::endl;
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return intVal; 
    }
    ~MyInt()
    {
        std::cout << "Destroyed!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int testFunc(const std::shared_ptr<MyInt>& obj1) 
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    
    auto localObj = obj1;
    cout<<"localObj.count:" << localObj.use_count() << endl;
    cout << "localObj:" << *localObj << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    
    {
    cout<< "globalObj.count:" << globalObj.use_count() << endl;
    cout << "globalObj:" << *globalObj << endl;
    
    testFunc(globalObj);
    
    cout << "globalObj.count:" << globalObj.use_count() << endl;
    cout << "globalObj:" << *globalObj << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Constucted!
> globalObj.count:1
> globalObj:5
> localObj.count:2
> localObj:5
> globalObj.count:1
> globalObj:5
> Destroyed!

You can test it here:
https://onlinegdb.com/tXqnoysmT